# use margin-top with scroll event to fix one div with relative position in some of scrolling areas makes lag

Tags: css, scroll, margin, addeventlistener

I am trying to make some animations when the user scrolls by vanilla js.

I put the event listener on 'scroll' but it seems that the event is triggered just after the scroll is over. I tried to add a margin-top to move some divs slower on scroll or to fix one in some of scroll areas but it causes shakes in screen because of scrolling and adding margin-top doesn't happen the same time.

Is it possible to listen the scroll event before it happens? If not, how it would be possible to keep some div fixed to window by adding margin-top to a relative div without lagging?

Adding margin top in this way is completely smooth when scrolling is done by scroll bar, the problem happens when I use mouse wheel.

```html
<html>

<body>
    <p>
        test
    </p>
    <p>
        test
    </p>
    <p>
        test
    </p>
    <p>
        test
    </p>
    <p>
        test
    </p>
    <p>
        test
    </p>
    <p>
        test
    </p>
    <p>
        test
    </p>
    <p>
        test
    </p>
    <p>
        test
    </p>
    <h1 id='custom-sticky'>
        test
    </h1>
    <p>
        test
    </p>
    <p>
        test
    </p>
    <p>
        test
    </p>
    <p>
        test
    </p>
    <p>
        test
    </p>
    <p>
        test
    </p>
    <p>
        test
    </p>
    <p>
        test
    </p>
    <p>
        test
    </p>
    <p>
        test
    </p>
    <p>
        test
    </p>
    <p>
        test
    </p>
    <p>
        test
    </p>
    <p>
        test
    </p>
    <p>
        test
    </p>
    <p>
        test
    </p>
    <p>
        test
    </p>
    <p>
        test
    </p>
    <p>
        test
    </p>
    <p>
        test
    </p>
    <p>
        test
    </p>
    <p>
        test
    </p>
    <p>
        test
    </p>
    <p>
        test
    </p>
    <p>
        test
    </p>
    <p>
        test
    </p>
    <p>
        test
    </p>
    <p>
        test
    </p>
    <p>
        test
    </p>
    <p>
        test
    </p>
    <p>
        test
    </p><p>
        test
    </p>
    <p>
        test
    </p>
    <p>
        test
    </p>
    <p>
        test
    </p>
    <p>
        test
    </p>
    <p>
        test
    </p>
    <p>
        test
    </p>
    <p>
        test
    </p>
    <p>
        test
    </p>
    <p>
        test
    </p>
    <p>
        test
    </p>
    <p>
        test
    </p>
    <p>
        test
    </p>
    <p>
        test
    </p>
    <p>
        test
    </p>
    <p>
        test
    </p>
    <p>
        test
    </p>
    <script>
        const customSticky = document.getElementById('custom-sticky')
        document.addEventListener('scroll',(e)=> {
            if(window.scrollY < 200){
                customSticky.style.marginTop = 0
            } else if(window.scrollY > 200 && window.scrollY < 2000){
                customSticky.style.marginTop = (window.scrollY - 200)+'px'
            } else {
                customSticky.style.marginTop = 1800
            }
        })
    </script>
</body>
</html>
```

Comment: Could you please add a code snippet?

Comment: @BastienRobert i have added a simple code snippet to the question

Comment: as you can see, using scroll bar results in smooth behaviour but using mouse wheel makes shakes

Answer (score 1):

After trying diffrent methods, I got that how i can get rid of the shakes.
I should prevent default action of mouse wheel. because the only thing that had been causing the shakes was browser animation for scrolling. so i eddited my code as below and the problem was solved

```html
<html>

<body>
    <p>
        test
    </p>
    <p>
        test
    </p>
    <p>
        test
    </p>
    <p>
        test
    </p>
    <p>
        test
    </p>
    <p>
        test
    </p>
    <p>
        test
    </p>
    <p>
        test
    </p>
    <p>
        test
    </p>
    <p>
        test
    </p>
    <h1 id='custom-sticky'>
        test
    </h1>
    <p>
        test
    </p>
    <p>
        test
    </p>
    <p>
        test
    </p>
    <p>
        test
    </p>
    <p>
        test
    </p>
    <p>
        test
    </p>
    <p>
        test
    </p>
    <p>
        test
    </p>
    <p>
        test
    </p>
    <p>
        test
    </p>
    <p>
        test
    </p>
    <p>
        test
    </p>
    <p>
        test
    </p>
    <p>
        test
    </p>
    <p>
        test
    </p>
    <p>
        test
    </p>
    <p>
        test
    </p>
    <p>
        test
    </p>
    <p>
        test
    </p>
    <p>
        test
    </p>
    <p>
        test
    </p>
    <p>
        test
    </p>
    <p>
        test
    </p>
    <p>
        test
    </p>
    <p>
        test
    </p>
    <p>
        test
    </p>
    <p>
        test
    </p>
    <p>
        test
    </p>
    <p>
        test
    </p>
    <p>
        test
    </p>
    <p>
        test
    </p>
    <p>
        test
    </p>
    <p>
        test
    </p>
    <p>
        test
    </p>
    <p>
        test
    </p>
    <p>
        test
    </p>
    <p>
        test
    </p>
    <p>
        test
    </p>
    <p>
        test
    </p>
    <p>
        test
    </p>
    <p>
        test
    </p>
    <p>
        test
    </p>
    <p>
        test
    </p>
    <p>
        test
    </p>
    <p>
        test
    </p>
    <p>
        test
    </p>
    <p>
        test
    </p>
    <p>
        test
    </p>
    <script>
        const customSticky = document.getElementById('custom-sticky')
        window.addEventListener("wheel", this.handleWheel, { passive: false });
        function handleWheel(e) {
            window.scrollBy(0, e.deltaY > 0 ? 56 : -56);
            e.preventDefault();
        }
        document.addEventListener('scroll', (e) => {
            if (window.scrollY < 200) {
                customSticky.style.marginTop = 0
            } else if (window.scrollY > 0 && window.scrollY < 2000) {
                customSticky.style.marginTop = (window.scrollY - 200) + 'px'
            } else {
                customSticky.style.marginTop = 1800 + 'px'
            }
        })
    </script>
</body>

</html>
```